Do unused tube bands expire?
I have a set of unused resistance tube bands that has been sitting in the box for years. Visually inspecting the bands, they appear pliable and show no signs of cracking.
Are these safe to use, or does the latex degrade over time without being used? I don't want them to unexpectedly snap.
I have tried searching this question, but have only found results relating to bands in active use.

Unfortunately, the answer may be yes.  Although I don't have experience with tube bands, I do have experience with the flat bands.  After a while, they tend to degrade and snap.
Often, one can tell this will happen as they begin to discolour as they weaken.  However, this isn't always the case.
I have found that keeping them in a sealed airtight container helps extend their longevity, as well as keeping them out of direct sunlight.
Personally, I use them until they snap on me, but that's not an experience everyone may be willing to endure.
